# how does Float.toString() and Integer.toString() works?

Tags: java, array-algorithms

How can i implement an algorithm to convert float or int to string?
I found one link
http://geeksforgeeks.org/forum/topic/amazon-interview-question-for-software-engineerdeveloper-0-2-years-about-algorithms-13

but i cant understand the algorithm given there

Comment: Are you asking how one might implement it, or how the JDK actually implements it?

Comment: its a interview question, i wont to implemt my own algo

Comment: integer to string is more simple. for double to string this guidlines might be helpful: [javaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double))

Answer (score 8):

the numbers 0-9 are sequential in most character encoding so twiddling with the integral value of it will help here:

```
int val;
String str="";
while(val>0){
    str = ('0'+(val%10)) + str;
    val /= 10;
}
```

Comment: This exemple is far better than the other. It is simple, it focus and the problem and is easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample of how to do the integer to string, from it I hope you'll be able to figure out how to do the float to string.

```
public String intToString(int value) {
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  if (value < 0) {
    buffer.append("-");
  }
  // MAX_INT is just over 2 billion, so start by finding the number of billions.
  int divisor = 1000000000;
  while (divisor > 0) {
    int digit = value / divisor;  // integer division, so no remainder.
    if (digit > 0) {
      buffer.append('0'+digit);
      value = value - digit * divisor; // subtract off the value to zero out that digit.
    }
    divisor = divisor / 10; // the next loop iteration should be in the 10's place to the right
  }
}
```

This is of course, very unoptimized, but it gives you a feel for how the most basic formatting is accomplished.

Note that the technique of `"" + x` is actually rewritten to be something like

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.append("");
buffer.append(String.valueOf(x));
buffer.toString();
```

So don't think that what is written is 100% exactly HOW it is done, look at is as what must happen in a larger view of things.

Comment: In the event that someone tries to swap out character sets with one that doesn't have it's digits sequentially (remember this is an interview question, not a real world problem) you can always implement the `buffer.append('0'+digit)` with a switch statement, like so `switch (digit) { case 0 :  buffer.append("0"); break; case 1 : buffer.append("1"); break; ... }`

Comment: Using StringBuffer is totally useless as the java compiler will replace string concatenation with one anyway.

Comment: @Nicolas, The compiler only replaces String concatenation with a `StringBuffer` in the event that all of the concatenations occur within the same localized block.  So, `System.out.println("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");` works just fine but, `String x = ""; for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { x = x + '0'+i; }` won't maintain a buffer between loop iterations.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is to pick off the least significant digit by taking the number remainder ten.  Then divide the number by 10 and repeat ... until you are left with zero.

Of course, it is a bit more complicated than that, especially in the `float` case.

---

> if i have a single digit in int fomrat then i need to insert it into char , how to convert int to char?

Easy:

```
int digit = ... /* 0 to 9 */
char ch = (char)('0' + digit);
```

Comment: agreed, but if i have a single digit in int fomrat then i need to  insert it into char , how to convert int to char?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can [read the code yourself.](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html)